# Upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 update and details

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

Black screen after upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10
How do I fix this?

Sony Vaio computer

This is an udate, but the problem is not yet solved. I tried the suggested fix (temporary/permenant) with "nomodset" and updated the grub file,but it did nothing. My screen does not go black. It first is purple, then light grey,then the video driver Nvidia shows, and the background comes up on the screen for about 10 seconds. This is where the icons and connections normally show up, but now they do not, and it goes blank back to light grey like the rest is not loading. However,there are only 2 icons, Netflix and Pandora,which cannot run because there's no Wi-Fi etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Somewhere on the interwebs there was a suggestion to purge and reinstall xorg and lightdm. Purging was succesful, but now I can't reinstall xorg, because of several unmet dependencies.

Comment: Also, if she is having the same issue as me, I couldn't find a solution in either of the posts you commented.

Comment: I have not found a solution either and do not have any icons do you know how to get them back? My system stays on the wallpaper for only about 10 seconds and goes blank